# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write' error in last line, need insight

Tags: python, string

Problem Prompt: write all file content into new file by skipping line 5 from following file.

Testfile:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
```

newFile:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line6
line7
```

Code:

```
testFile = 'C:/Users\Karan\Documents\\test.txt'
newFile = 'C:/Users\Karan\Documents\\newtext.txt'

for num, line in enumerate(testFile, 1):
    if num != 5:
        newFile.write(line)
```

```
Errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Karan/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.1/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 7, in <module>
    newFile.write(line)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I know it's an issue with the last line, But I've been pounding away at it all day and would really like a fresh set of eyes to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

`newFile` is the **name** of the file you wanted to open, **not** the File object created by actually opening the file with that name.

And indeed the error says "**str** has no attribute...", because the object you're using is a string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you did more correct in your code than some answers are giving you credit for -- particularly in your use of `enumerate()`.  It's the file opening, as well as possibly the file name strings, that are at issue here:

```
testFile_name = r"C:\Users\Karan\Documents\test.txt"
newFile_name = r"C:\Users\Karan\Documents\newtext.txt"

with open(testFile_name) as testFile:
    with open(newFile_name, 'w') as newFile:
        for number, line in enumerate(testFile, 1):
            if number != 5:
                newFile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `open()` to first *open* the files before you can read and write them.

```
with open('C:/Users\Karan\Documents\\test.txt') as testFile:
    File = testFile.readlines()

with open('C:/Users\Karan\Documents\\newtext.txt','w') as newFile:
    File.pop(4) # Remove the fifth line
    newFile.write(''.join(File))
```

---

UPDATE:

As stated in the comments by @cdlane, it's not a good practice to write the whole file into memory when unnecessary. Instead, write the file line by line:

```
with open('C:/Users\Karan\Documents\\test.txt','r') as testFile, open('C:/Users\Karan\Documents\\newtext.txt','w') as newFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(testFile, 1):
        if num != 5:
            newFile.write(line)
```

Comment: You're reading the entire file into memory which isn't necessary to solve this problem -- it can be approached one line in memory at a time. The OP had it right with their enumerate() call -- it starts at whatever number the programmer specifies.  Just the opening of files was at issue.